# Split value by delimeter SQL

Tags: sql, text, decimal, delimiter

I have a column (varchar) that shows a value as 44:45:00. I am writing a query and I want to convert 44:00:00 in a decimal number and want to use the following calculation

((44(part1) * 60) + 45(part2) ) / 60 = 44,75

The result should returned as a value and it should not create a new column.

[sql database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTf4Y.png)

Comment: Why is this tagged with `jquery`? o.O

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Andreas I believe that a lot of people mistake jquery for a query tag.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen But how? _"jQuery is a JavaScript library, ..."_ :/

Comment: @Andreas I know but I believe they write "query" and then select jquery without reading what the description is.

Comment: Please mention which dbms of what version you are using.

Comment: Does this value change often? Do you need the decimal value for more than this query? How often do you execute that query? Maybe an auto-calculated column would be a good idea (but that would be a question for https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Andreas , my apologies, carsten is correct. I clicked jquery instead of query.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur, sory I don't have to much experience in SQL query. What do you mean?

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: @Andreas, no I only need it for this query. The query will executed once per day. Yes a calculated column is possible, but how to do that :-)

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur Microsoft SQL server management studio ?

Comment: what is your sql server version. SQL Server 2017, SQL Server 2019 etc.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNurn 2017

Answer (score 0):

Databases support string functions.  The substring function is typically called `substr()` or `substring()` (or both).  Assuming the format is exactly what you specify, you can use:

```
select (cast(substr(col, 1, 2) as int) +
        cast(substr(col, 4, 2) as int) / 60.0
       )
```

Many databases have methods to simplify this.  But this approach should work in any database.

Comment: What about 400:500:600? OP not said it's a time.

Comment: I replaced "col" with my own columname, but I got an error

Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'substr' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @BaharYener . . . Then use `substring()`.  As I say in the answer, it depends on the database which you have not specified.

Comment: @GordonLinoff my apologies, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this one:

**Schema:**

> ```
> create table x(t_hours varchar(20));
> insert into x values('1:00:00');
> insert into x values('1:00:00');
> insert into x values('64:00:00');
> insert into x values('2:00:00');
> insert into x values('2:00:00');
> insert into x values('1:30:00');
> insert into x values('110:40:12');
> insert into x values('44:38:24');
> insert into x values('14:00:00');
> insert into x values('8:00:00');
> insert into x values('8:00:00');
> insert into x values('47:00:00');
> insert into x values('16:00:00');
> insert into x values('1:00:00');
> insert into x values('8:00:00');
> insert into x values('16:00:00');
> insert into x values('1:33:36');
> insert into x values('19:46:48');
> insert into x values('2:00:00');
> insert into x values('2:00:00');
> insert into x values('8:00:00');
> insert into x values('8:00:00');
> insert into x values('4:30:00');
> insert into x values('6:30:00');
> insert into x values('0:15:00');
> insert into x values('1:00:00');
> insert into x values('32:00:00');
> insert into x values('8:00:00');
> insert into x values('17:00:00');
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> select t_hours,left(t_hours,charindex(':',t_hours)-1)+ left(substring(t_hours,charindex(':',t_hours)+1,len(t_hours)-charindex(':',t_hours)),charindex(':',substring(t_hours,charindex(':',t_hours)+1,len(t_hours)-charindex(':',t_hours)))-1)/60.0
> from x
> ```

**Output:**

> | t_hours | (No column name) |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1:00:00 | 1.000000 |
> | 1:00:00 | 1.000000 |
> | 64:00:00 | 64.000000 |
> | 2:00:00 | 2.000000 |
> | 2:00:00 | 2.000000 |
> | 1:30:00 | 1.500000 |
> | 110:40:12 | 110.666666 |
> | 44:38:24 | 44.633333 |
> | 14:00:00 | 14.000000 |
> | 8:00:00 | 8.000000 |
> | 8:00:00 | 8.000000 |
> | 47:00:00 | 47.000000 |
> | 16:00:00 | 16.000000 |
> | 1:00:00 | 1.000000 |
> | 8:00:00 | 8.000000 |
> | 16:00:00 | 16.000000 |
> | 1:33:36 | 1.550000 |
> | 19:46:48 | 19.766666 |
> | 2:00:00 | 2.000000 |
> | 2:00:00 | 2.000000 |
> | 8:00:00 | 8.000000 |
> | 8:00:00 | 8.000000 |
> | 4:30:00 | 4.500000 |
> | 6:30:00 | 6.500000 |
> | 0:15:00 | 0.250000 |
> | 1:00:00 | 1.000000 |
> | 32:00:00 | 32.000000 |
> | 8:00:00 | 8.000000 |
> | 17:00:00 | 17.000000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c83772cf45e14a4f0b6cce43aa00fbc4)*

Comment: What about ``400:500:600``? OP not said it's a time.

Comment: I got the error 

Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: please share the string for which u got the error.

Comment: I used select  left(t_hours,2)  + substring(t_hours,4,2)  / 60.0 from X and t_hours column has datatype varchar (15) 

Below some example values from this column

01:00:00
01:00:00
64:00:00
02:00:00
02:00:00
01:30:00
110:40:12
44:38:24
14:00:00
08:00:00
08:00:00
47:00:00
16:00:00
01:00:00
08:00:00
16:00:00
01:33:36
19:46:48
02:00:00
02:00:00
08:00:00
08:00:00
04:30:00
06:30:00
00:15:00
01:00:00
32:00:00
08:00:00
17:00:00

Comment: You have three digits in hour part. Use my revised answer.

Comment: This is working perfect! And the next step is to put this value in my query. I have to SUM this values, see part "SUM(t_hours) as 'Hours' "

 SELECT CONVERT(varchar(12),d_date, 103) as 'Date', SUM(t_hours) as 'Hours'
  FROM X
  WHERE [t_department] = 'X' AND t_invoice = 'Yes' OR t_handling = 'X' OR t_Handling = 'X'
  GROUP BY [d_date] 
  ORDER BY [d_date] ASC;

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur

Comment: One minute brother. Let me have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with custom separator like this:

```
DECLARE @foo VARCHAR(100) = '440:4500:00';
DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ':';

SELECT (CAST(SUBSTRING(@foo, 0, CHARINDEX(@separator, @foo)) AS INT) * 60
        + CAST(SUBSTRING(
                            @foo,
                            LEN(SUBSTRING(@foo, 0, CHARINDEX(@separator, @foo))) + 2,
                            CHARINDEX(@separator, @foo, LEN(SUBSTRING(@foo, 0, CHARINDEX(@separator, @foo))))
                        ) AS INT)
       )/ 60.0;
```